Getting user's email address in Google Script
At the top of a Google form it shows the account that is logged in to enter the form data. How do I  grab that account in a script? And if in the setting of the Google Form I select Verify under the Responses section so it shows the user's email address, how can I grab that in a script?
Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() will only give me my name no matter which computer I run it on.

Have you tried getRespondentEmail() or setCollectEmail(collect)?

Are you allowed to enable the option to collect email addresses from the form?

Just for clarification: setCollectEmail adds a "required" Email field to the start of form where the respondent must enter an email address. It does NOT capture the email address in the so-called "header". getRespondentEmail() will return/display the email address entered by the respondent (per setCollectEmail) and collectsEmail will display the status of setCollectEmail (true/false).

At the top of a Google form it shows the account that is logged in to enter the form data.
This is not strictly true. In any event, this email address cannot be accessed.

Signed in vs NOT Signed in
If the respondent has signed into Google then their Google email address will be displayed at the top of the Form. However, it is NOT required by default that a respondent must sign into Google (or even have a Google account) in order to submit a Google Form.
In the case where a respondent is NOT signed into Google, the Form displays a message "Sign in to Google to save your progress", and a Learn more hyperlink explains that "Google Forms automatically saves your progress for 30 days when you're signed in to your Google Account so that you can work across devices or take a break without losing a step."
Collect email addresses
There are three options for collection of email addreses:

"Do not collect" (default)
"Responder input"
"Verified"

Responder input

setCollectEmail adds a "required" Email field to the start of form where the respondent must enter an email address (any email address will do; it need NOT be a GMail address).

It does NOT capture the email address in the so-called "header".


getRespondentEmail will return/display the email address from a Form response (per setCollectEmail)
collectsEmail will display the status of setCollectEmail (true/false).

"Verified"
This is the method that will require the respondent to disclose a Google email address.

Google WorkSpace users can access requiresLogin.

This requires the respondent to login to a Google account before responding.
When set to true, the "required" Email question changes to a checkbox with text:




"Record >logged in google email address< as the email to be included with my
response".

Of course the respondent can change their account, and so the relevant email displayed in the "required" field will change accordingly.

If the script command is not available to a user, this can still be set manually: "Collect email addresses" = "Verified".


How to show a respondent's email address
Linked Spreadsheet

If the Form is linked to a spreadsheet, then the "Email Address" will be a separate field and can be accessed manually and/or through Event Objects.

The following is a script option to display respondent email addresses.



function getRespondentEmail() {

  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  // Gets an array of the form's responses.
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();
  // Loops through the responses and logs each respondent's email to the console.
  // To collect respondent emails, ensure that Form.setCollectEmail(collect) is set to true.
  for (const formResponse of formResponses) {
    Logger.log(`Respondent Email: ${formResponse.getRespondentEmail()}`);
  }
}



requiresLogin is deprecated as of time of writing this comment.
